# Unbalanced CSS columns in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I want to display some Bootstrap list groups dynamically in multiple columns using [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts), but I'm getting some weird spacing issues in Chrome. Firefox works perfectly. It looks like exactly the issue [this guy had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017065/extra-space-beneath-css-column-layout?rq=1), but he never got an answer, possibly because he didn't provide a good example. So I will provide a good example.

CSS (loaded after Bootstrap):

```
.columns {
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
     -moz-column-width: 200px;
          column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
     -moz-column-gap: 20px;
          column-gap: 20px;
  width: 600px;
}

.list-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width:  100%;      
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Here it is on Bootply.](http://www.bootply.com/4kvDje3M5L) Everything is fine in Firefox: the first 3 list groups go in the first column, the next 3 go in the second. But in Chrome, the first 4 go in the first column, leaving the second column very short with only 2. How can I get it to balance?

(I've also observed another problem described in [the same question I linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017065/extra-space-beneath-css-column-layout?rq=1) where sometimes Chrome will create a big margin under the columns, but I'll leave that for a separate question later.)

Comment: It is all about `column-fill: balance`, which is not supported by chrome, and is the default value of `moz-column-fill` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill. Try set `moz-column-fill : auto` for POC.

Comment: `.columns { height : 400px; }`   seems to "solve" the problem in chrome, but I am sure you are aware of this and want a real solution instead.

Comment: `-moz-column-fill : auto` seems to put all of the list groups in one column. Does that make sense? It's still different than Chrome, which splits it 4 and 2. According to [this](http://www.the-haystack.com/2012/06/01/multi-column-confusion/) Chrome is supposed to balance by default. It seems like maybe it's trying to balance but just doing a really bad job?

Comment: And you're right, I would like a "real" solution, otherwise I have to use JS to dynamically estimate what the height should be, since I don't have a fixed number of columns or a fixed number of elements inside the columns...

Comment: hey @dumbmatter, to the first - no, it does not make sense, it was not an answer - it was proof of concept that column-fill works on FF (it responds, Chrome or IE does not). To the next, I dont think you can achieve a "real" solution, sorry to say. If your columns are dynamic, you must go to javascript. I think it is weird, by the way, that it is only FF (Mozilla-engine) that supports column-fill. I cannot see the reason why the other engines should not. It is part of a (not confirmed) standard.

Comment: "maybe it's trying to balance but just doing a really bad job" - that could be an explanation. But who knows.

Comment: According to CanIUse, column fill is supported by Chrome starting with version 50.

Comment: ... yet it is still buggy in Chrome 58 if set to "balance" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a stupid question, but have you looked into flexbox?

```
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
     -moz-column-width: 200px;
          column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
     -moz-column-gap: 20px;
          column-gap: 20px;
  width: 600px;
}

.list-group {
  display: inline-block;
      width: 300px;
}
```

**EDIT** Going through unanswered questions and didn't realize how old this is.

Comment: Old questions still deserve attention :) Your code works, but actually it seems that the original code in my question also now works in the current version of Chrome. What a world of abundance we live in!

Comment: I was actually going to say that initially, but then figured, hey someone else might be on an older version of BS for some reason, why not! Glad both work!